# Unexpected null value Flutterflow

Tags: firebase, flutterflow

Could someone please help me with this problem?

I'm testing the app on Flutterflow, and the pages I use "backendquery" for "document from reference" are generating an "unexpected null value" error.

[Unexpected Null Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/099Li.png)

I know it's because of the query because when I delete it, the error disappears, but it is necessary to use the backend query for these specific pages. I've already checked all the widgets and none of them have "null value", all of them already have "default variable value". here is the code used for the widget that has a query behind. I couldn't find any "null value".

```
    // Generated code for this Text Widget...
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 0, 0, 12),
  child: Text(
    valueOrDefault<String>(
      jobDetailsJobVacanciesRecord.jobTitle,
      'título da vaga',
    ),
    style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).titleMedium.override(
          fontFamily: 'Urbanist',
          color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).dark600,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Your question should show the code (a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)) that doesn't work the way you expect. Without that, it's highly unlikely that you'll get good feedback on what's wrong and how to fix it. We should be able to copy what you have and run it for ourselves with the instructions you provide.

Comment: just edited the question with the widget code whats shows "null value" error.